# Comparing Java's lambda expression with Swift's function type

Tags: java, swift, function, lambda

In Swift, function types are treated as first class citizens, and can be used anywhere, as any other types. Its syntax is straightforward, and can be easily understood and used.

On the other hand, Java does support function programming via lambda expressions, but in general, I have found it less intuitive, harder to understand, and seemingly more restrictive, compared to Swift's function type.

My question is, since the purpose of Swift's function type and Java's lambda expression is to achieve functional programming, is there anything that Swift's function type can do, but Java's lambda expression can't? Or are they both equally powerful?

Comment: Consider adding [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) to the comparison.

Comment: Something that should be considered is the performance/bloat hit in Java : https://realm.io/news/360andev-jake-wharton-java-hidden-costs-android/ Basically, Swift's implementations of closures and function types are part of the core of the language. Java's implementations are tacked on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is incorrect to compare Java's [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (implementation) and Swift's [functional type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/function-type) (type). But it is possible to compare Java's lambda to Swifts's [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). And Swift's functional type to Java's [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8).

Closures are more powerful than lambdas:

1. (major) Closures may capture non-constant variables, e. g

   ```
   func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
       var runningTotal = 0
       return () -> Int {
           runningTotal += amount
           return runningTotal
       }
   }
   ```
2. (minor) Closures support shorthand argument names, e.g.

   ```
   reversedNames = names.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 } )
   ```
3. (minor) Trailing closures support, e.g.

   ```
   someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
       // trailing closure's body goes here
   }
   ```

From the other hand, functional interfaces are more powerful than functional types. They allows to declare additional methods, e.g. [java.util.Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that defines a bunch of convenient methods for comparator building, such as `reversed` and `thenComparing`.

Comment: It's a hack perhaps, but you can use an array in Java to act like your case #1, i.e. `final int[] runningValue = new int[] { 0 };` and then `() -> { return ++runningValue[0]; }`.

Answer (score 3):

I can only think of one restriction in the Java functional API.

In order to write a lambda expression in Java, you must need an interface with one method. There are already some interfaces made for you in the JDK, but IMHO, their names are less descriptive than the swift's function types. You can't guess immediately that `Predicate<T>` accepts a `T` parameter and returns a `boolean`. On the other hand, `T -> Bool` is much cleaner and clearer.

I think other than that, Java's lambda expressions can do anything that swift function types can.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to study both in any case, me as java developer, can say that functional programming its a hard topic to understand, but I now understand a lot of features, I don't know if you can use streams in SWIFT when using closures, once you get the functional interfaces and how to implement lambdas, you will realize that you can make a lot of things with a few lines of code in a more readable way with lambda/streams combination, I think oracle had put a lot of effort on that, and if you use well you can make cleaner and better code, to answer your question both are powerful, but I agree lambdas are more alike closures of swift.